# Admob Ads not showing on Android but works on iOS -- Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

Admob ads are showing on iOS but not on android.

I get the error code:

> W/flutter (19625): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
>
> I/Ads     (19625): Ad failed to load : 0

```
const String AD_MOB_APP_ID = 'ca-app-pub-4557742583730339~4084223970';
const String AD_MOB_AD_ID = 'ca-app-pub-4557742583730339/9589979329';


  static final MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = new MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    keywords: <String>['facts', 'world', 'knowledge'],
    childDirected: false,
    // testDevices: <String>['54A247BAD1B1581AA228E503FA71DFEB'],
  );

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return new BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      adUnitId: AD_MOB_AD_ID,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
    );
  }

  BannerAd _bannerAd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: AD_MOB_APP_ID);
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()
      ..load()
      ..show(anchorOffset: 100.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: would you please add some code?

Comment: Try to paste some code otherwise this post will be closed soon.

Comment: Code added, thats all the code StockOverFlow allows me to add

Answer (score 0):

The ads are showing now, seems I just needed to wait a bit for Admob to activate.

Comment: Activating Admob.?